# Computing surface area/volume of spherical pyramid

Tags: geometry, area, volume, spheres

[image: spherical pyramids][1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lSyUf1Z7W0)
I want to compute surface area/volume of given 'spherical pyramid' (I don't know whether it is a legit name). What are the answers when $\angle AOB=\angle BOC=\angle AOC = 60 ^\circ$ and $\angle AOB=\angle BOC=\angle AOC = 45 ^\circ$? If there is no geometrical solution, I want to know how to solve in computational tools.

Comment: Are you asking about a piece of a  [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), either $1/6$ or $1/8$?

Comment: Is the point $O$ at the centre of the sphere ?

Comment: Are the points $A$ , $B$ and $C$ on the sphere ?

Comment: @WW1:  If it is a piece of a spherical cap, $O$ would be the center of the circle that forms its base.

Comment: Aforest below answered my question. Thanks for all

Answer (score 2):

The surface area of the [spherical triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html) $S_{ABC}=R^2E$ where $R$ is the radius and $E$ is the spherical excess which can be solved by [L'Huilier's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHuiliersTheorem.html).

The volume $V$ can therefore be given by the area ratio of the sphere:
\begin{align}
V&=V_{sphere}{S_{ABC}\over S_{sphere}}\\
&=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3{R^2E\over 4\pi R^{2}}\\
&={R^3E\over 3}
\end{align}

When $\angle AOB=\angle BOC=\angle AOC = 60 ^\circ$, we have $\tan\tfrac{1}{4}E 
= (\tan\tfrac{\pi}{12})^{3/2}$, and when $\angle AOB=\angle BOC=\angle AOC = 45 ^\circ$, we have $\tan\tfrac{1}{4}E 
= \sqrt{(\tan\tfrac{3\pi}{16})(\tan\tfrac{\pi}{16})^{3}}$.

Comment: Way harder than I expected. Thank you!!